# How to correctly configure a WCF REST service endpoint?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, service, endpoint

I am planning to host multiple RESTful services based on different contracts. There are a lot of similar questions but my web.config file looks different, I don't know why.

Here is part of my web.config file :

```
    <standardEndpoints>
          <webHttpEndpoint>
            <standardEndpoint name="" 
                              helpEnabled="true" 
                              automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true">
            </standardEndpoint>
          </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
```

Here is my service declaration in my web application :

```
    RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("bob/chocolate", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(RESTchocolate)));
    RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("bob/vanilla", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(RESTvanilla)));
```

Only the first Route seems to be working (tested using the nice "bob/chocolate/help" endpoint feature of .NET to list the methods available) which does not surprises me really, but how should I modify my web.config file ? Does any of you know how to do this ? Do I need to modify something else ?

For those wondering, my contracts are valid.

I get "Endpoint not found" in a nice .NET display if I try to reach the second endpoint in my browser.

EDIT :

I added the following node to my config file...

```
    <services>
      <service name="chocolate">
        <endpoint address="bob/chocolate" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="chocolate" contract="RESTapi.IRESTchocolate" />
      </service>
      <service name="vanilla">
        <endpoint address="bob/vanilla" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="vanilla" contract="RESTapi.IRESTvanilla" />
      </service>
    </services>
```

But I get the same behaviour. The problem is still here

EDIT : and here is my complete config file as requested (without the node above) :

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
      <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
        <authentication mode="None"></authentication>
      </system.web>
      <system.serviceModel>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true">
        </serviceHostingEnvironment>
         <standardEndpoints>
          <webHttpEndpoint>
            <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"></standardEndpoint>
          </webHttpEndpoint>
        </standardEndpoints>
      </system.serviceModel>
      <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
      </system.webServer>

    </configuration>
```

Comment: Can you post the complete system.serviceModel section. Might be easy to help you out

Comment: @Rajesh : Just edited. This is a very basic one so I don't understand what is going on

Comment: Can you try adding  multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" on the serviceHostingEnvironment element in your config and see if that gets it working. I tried the same sample and it works

Comment: Also try including the below entry in your config for URL routing: <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>

Comment: @Rajesh : that did not do the trick, same behaviour and 404 error when reaching the methods

Comment: How are you hosting this service, self hosting, IIS, other ?

Comment: @TommyGrovnes : So far I am only using Visual Studio development server.

Comment: If you add the vanilla route before the chocolate one, can you then reach it and not the other ?

Comment: The first route works but the second doesn't

Answer (score 1):

I really recommend you install the [WCF REST Service Template 40](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fbc7e5c1-a0d2-41bd-9d7b-e54c845394cd?SRC=VSIDE) and take a look at the bootstrap.

Web.config

```
<standardEndpoints>
  <webHttpEndpoint>
    <!-- 
        Configure the WCF REST service base address via the global.asax.cs file and the default endpoint 
        via the attributes on the <standardEndpoint> element below
    -->
    <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
  </webHttpEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>
```

Global.asax

```
// Edit the base address of Service1 by replacing the "Service1" string below
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("Service1", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(Service1)));
```

Comment: If I'm understanding right, you didn't answer OP's question which is how to configure 2 services hosted by the same 1 application. Here is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6772983/548098